# How to activate onmouseover after specific duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover, universal-analytics

How is it possible to define a specific duration on onmouseover function ?
For example, after 500ms hover the element, onmouseover starts to run (so, if the user doesn't saty more than 500ms, onmouseover doesn't run).

In my case, I would like to apply an event (Universal Analytics).
If the user stays more than 500ms hover the element, the event will be activate.

```
<img class="element" src="images/example.gif" onmouseover="ga('send', 'event', 'title');"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not call function from HTML onclick if it can be avoided. Add event listener with jQuery. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html

```
$('element').on('onmouseover', function(){

    setTimeout(function() {
      ga('send','event','title');
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timeout method to send the event after given time.

```
<img class="element" src="images/example.gif" onmouseover="setTimeout(function(){ga('send', 'event', 'title');},1000)"/>
```